# How run robolectric inside AOSP

Tags: android, android-source, robolectric

I try run robolectric inside AOSP

my Android.bp file looks like

```
android_robolectric_test {
    name: "MyRoboTests",

     srcs: [
             "src/**/*.java",
         ],

    static_libs: [
        "SettingsLib-robo-testutils",
        "android-support-annotations",
        "androidx.test.core",
        "androidx.test.runner",
        "androidx.test.ext.junit",
        "androidx.test.espresso.core",
    ],

    java_resource_dirs: ["config", "resources"],
    instrumentation_for: "MyProject",
    test_options: {
        timeout: 36000,
        shards: 10,
    },

    coverage_libs: [
        "Settings-core",
        "SettingsLib",
        "SettingsLib-search",
    ],
}
```

test looks:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class UsbTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Object object = new Object();
        assertNotNull(object);
    }
}
```

I try run with atest

```
$ atest -c MyRoboTests
```

But test does not run. Out of console looks:

```
==================
Notice:
  We collect anonymous usage statistics in accordance with our Content Licenses (https://source.android.com/setup/start/licenses), Contributor License Agreement (https://opensource.google.com/docs/cla/), Privacy Policy (https://policies.google.com/privacy) and Terms of Service (https://policies.google.com/terms).
==================


Finding Tests...
Found 'MyUsbTest' as MODULE


Running Tests...
Run 'atest --history' to review test result history.
```

Test does not work
I don't understand What is wrong Could you help me with running robolectric for AOSP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigation, I have figured out that Robolectric isn't run with atest.

[In google source documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/settings/info-architecture#implementation) I found the link to readme:

> If the change is submitted to AOSP, then a unit test is required. To
> get more information about how to write Robolectric based tests, see
> the readme file packages/apps/Settings/tests/robotests/README.md.

[README.md](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/tests/robotests/README.md)

Running a single test class

```
$ croot
$ make RunSettingsRoboTests ROBOTEST_FILTER=<ClassName>
```

So in my sample I for my Android.bp file

```
//############################################################
// Settings Robolectric test target.                         #
//############################################################
android_robolectric_test {
    name: "MyRoboTests",

     srcs: [
             "src/**/*.java",
         ],

    static_libs: [
        "SettingsLib-robo-testutils",
        "android-support-annotations",
        "androidx.test.core",
        "androidx.test.runner",
        "androidx.test.ext.junit",
        "androidx.test.espresso.core",
    ],

    java_resource_dirs: ["config", "resources"],
    instrumentation_for: "MyProject",
    test_options: {
        timeout: 36000,
        shards: 10,
    },

}
```

To create a command I need to add "Run" to the module name  "MyRoboTests"

```
$ make RunMyRoboTests ROBOTEST_FILTER=UsbTest
```

Note this!

You should correct create folders structure for roblectrics test like [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/tests/robotests/):
[image]

Do not forget for "src" package inside  "robotests" package.

After running tests I get the output:

```
============================================
[100% 10/10] build out/target/product/generic_car_x86_64/obj/ROBOLECTRIC/RunMyBoboRoboTests0_intermediates/test.fake
RunMyBoboRoboTests0: 
RunMyBoboRoboTests0: Time: 15.395
RunMyBoboRoboTests0: 
RunMyBoboRoboTests0: OK (12 tests)
RunMyBoboRoboTests0:
```

to open result files:

```
$ nautilus out/target/product/generic_car_x86_64/obj/ROBOLECTRIC/RunMyBoboRoboTests0_intermediates/
```

[image]

I hope this helps someone. Happy coding!